# How to get CPU and memory usage of pod in percentage using promethus

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, prometheus, grafana, promql

I want to display pod details in the following format using promql/Prometheus.

[image: Image1]

Furthermore, I want to display CPU and memory utilization of application/component in below format using promql

[image: Image2]

promql query: sum(container_memory_working_set_bytes) by (pod)

I can get the consumed memory by pod using above query.

How to calculate percentage of memory used ? I am not able to fetch memory limit of stateful pod using promql
Could you please suggest any query/API details ?

Comment: Which queries have you tried?

Comment: sum(kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores) by (pod)

sum(container_memory_working_set_bytes) by (pod)

Comment: I can get the consumed memory of pod using above query. How to calculate percentage of memory used ? I am not able to fetch memory limit of pod using promql

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Per-pod CPU usage in percentage (the query doesn't return CPU usage for pods without CPU limits)

```
100 * max(
  rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total[5m])
    / on (container, pod)
  kube_pod_container_resource_limits{resource="cpu"}
) by (pod)
```

The `kube_pod_container_resource_limits` metric can be scraped incorrectly if scrape config for [kube-state-metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/) pod is improperly configured. In this case the original `pod` label for this metric is moved to the `exported_pod` label because of `honor_labels` behavior - see [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#scrape_config) for details. In this case [label_replace](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_replace) function must be used for moving `exported_pod` label to `pod` label:

```
100 * max(
  rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total[5m])
    / on (container, pod)
  label_replace(kube_pod_container_resource_limits{resource="cpu"}, "pod", "$1", "exported_pod", "(.+)")
) by (pod)
```

#### Per-pod memory usage in percentage (the query doesn't return memory usage for pods without memory limits)

```
100 * max(
  container_memory_working_set_bytes
    / on (container, pod)
  kube_pod_container_resource_limits{resource="memory"}
) by (pod)
```

If the `kube_pod_container_resource_limits` metric is scraped incorrectly as mentioned above, then the [label_replace](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_replace) function must be used for moving `exported_pod` label value to `pod`:

```
100 * max(
  container_memory_working_set_bytes
    / on (container, pod)
  label_replace(kube_pod_container_resource_limits{resource="memory"}, "pod", "$1", "exported_pod", "(.+)")
) by (pod)
```

Comment: Is there any reason for the CPU usage percent query to return values above 100%? How such results (usage beyond limit) could be interpreted.. ?

Comment: I got this error: `execution: execution: execution: multiple matches for labels: many-to-one matching must be explicit (group_left/group_right)`.

Answer (score 2):

**For CPU percentage**

```
max by (pod) (sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{namespace="$namespace",container_name!="POD",container_name!="",container!="monitoring-daemon"}[5m])) / sum(kube_pod_container_resource_limits{namespace="$namespace", resource="cpu"})) * 100
```

**For Memory percentage**

```
avg((avg (container_memory_working_set_bytes{pod="<Podname>"}) by (container_name , pod ))/ on (container_name , pod)(avg (container_spec_memory_limit_bytes>0 ) by (container_name, pod))*100)
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this for memory:

```
round(max by (pod)(max_over_time(container_memory_usage_bytes{namespace="$namespace",pod=~".*" }[5m]))/ on (pod) (max by (pod) (kube_pod_container_resource_limits)) * 100,0.01)
```

And this for CPU :

```
max by (pod) (sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{namespace="$namespace",container_name!="POD",container_name!="",container!="monitoring-daemon"}[5m])) / sum(kube_pod_container_resource_limits{namespace="$namespace", resource="cpu"})) * 100
```