# Estimate pod level cpu and memory utilization as a whole of node level

Tags: linux, kubernetes, billing

I order to derive pod billing I want to understand how can I calculate the logic to determine the billing. For example I have a kubernetes cluster with minimum 3 nodes which can scale to 6 nodes. So for example my node has 4 cpu and 16gb memory and each node costs me 100 dollars. I can get the infra metrics from Tools like prometheus. Now imagine if a pod 1 ran on the node A for 20 mins pod 2 ran on node for 3 min and pod 3 ran on node 1 for 20 hours how should I go about building the logic for determining the charge of a pod in terms of overall node charge.

If my line of thought is wrong then please guide what my line of thought should be.

Comment: You could peak at how [opencost](https://github.com/opencost/opencost) does it

Comment: I took a look at opencost but since we cannot expose the azure price sheet confidential information. I need to do a retrospective analysis based on bill.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way that comes to my mind is to setup an architecture composed of `Prometheus` and `Grafana` to visulize the usage.

`Prometheus` provides a [functional query language called `PromQL` (Prometheus Query Language)](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/) that allows the user select and aggregate time series data in real time, filtering on the pod name and, thus, you can determine the infrastructure usage even if the pod changes node.

An example of `PromQL` sintax filtering on the pod name:

```
sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{namespace="$namespace",
  pod_name=~"$podName",container_name!=""}[1h])) by (pod_name)
```

As you can see the above query is not relatad to the node but only to the pod name and namespace.

Another example about data aggregation and custom calculation you can perform with PromQL is, for example, if you want to know the average CPU usage in percentage per each node for the last 25 minutes:

```
100 * avg(1 - rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[25m])) by (instance)
```

Finally, `Grafana` will help you to draw dashboards, add calculations, and so on. In particular, if you have more complicated calculation you can benefit from Grafana that allows you to create variables. In your case, if you create 2 variables:

- var1 - one with the average CPU available per node
- var2 - one with the CPU usage by a pod_name
- `100*var1/var2` to get the percentage of CPU usage by pod_name

Take a look also at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63347233/how-to-get-cpu-and-memory-usage-of-pod-in-percentage-using-promethus).

Comment: I too thought on these lines but were I am struggling is how do I say CPU and memory used at 10% and 40% for 25 mins would say this is like X % of node utilisation.

Comment: I extended my answer to try to reply to your comment. Hope it helps more now.

Comment: I will try out this but since we use a another monitoring tool datadog will try to leverage the equivalent of this in datadog.